# Cохранение каждого файла docx в отдельный файл xlsx (в одной папке), используя цикл for

Tags: python, pandas, for, docx, xlsx

уважаемые программисты!
Прошу помощи в решении вопроса.
Имеется работающий код для считывания таблиц в одном файле docx (MS Word 2019) и сохранения данных в файле xlsx (MS Excel 2019).

```
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd

document = Document("D:\путь...\ivanova.docx")
tables = document.tables
df = pd.DataFrame()

for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        text = [cell.text for cell in row.cells]
        df = df.append([text], ignore_index=True)
df.to_excel("D:\тот же путь...\ivanova.xlsx")
```

Попробовал его расширить для обработки каждого файла docx в папке и сохранения их в индивидуальные файлы xlsx поочередно.
В результате, пока, имеется такой код - не работает.

```
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd
import glob
allfiles = glob.glob("*.docx")
document = Document(allfiles)
tables = document.tables
df = pd.DataFrame()
for document in Document(allfiles):
    for table in document.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            text = [cell.text for cell in row.cells]
            df = df.append([text], ignore_index=True)
df.to_excel("*.xlsx")
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?
Возможно, для этого требуется другой путь решения?

Comment: вы можете привести ссылки на воспроизводимые примеры данных (`.docx`)?

Comment: "Не работает" - это очень абстрактное заявление. Что это значит?

Comment: "Не работает" - значит, что появляется ошибка (какая именно, уже сказать не могу) и результат не получен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не запускал твой код, исходил из твоего заявления, что он работает.

Твой код в виде функции convert_docx_to_xlsx. Функция read_folder считывает имена всех файлов в формате docx в папке, где запускается скрипт. Если нужна другая папка, укажи её в path_in. Затем в цикле по всем найденным файлам отрабатывает твоя функция.

Попробуй так:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document

def read_folder(path_in):
    list_images = []
    for i in os.listdir(path_in):
        if i[i.rfind(".") + 1:].lower() in ['docx']:
            list_images.append(os.path.join(path_in, i))
    return list_images

def convert_docx_to_xlsx(path):
    document = Document(path)
    tables = document.tables # вот это не работает, попробуй удалить
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for table in document.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            text = [cell.text for cell in row.cells]
            df = df.append([text], ignore_index=True)
    new_path = path.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.xlsx'
    df.to_excel(new_path)


path_in = os.getcwd() #или указать путь к нужной папке с файлами
for i in read_folder(path_in):
    convert_docx_to_xlsx(i)
```

Comment: Никита, код запускается и и без изменений. Планируемый результат получен. Спасибо за помощь! Конечно, мне надо будет изучить данные функции подробнее.